# Speed up execution of query to find sequential rows that have a changed value

Tags: sql, db2

My goal is to go through my dataset, compare each `ITEM_NO`/`LOC` day-by-day, and identify days where the `VAL` has changed from the day before.  Right now, I do that by sorting, creating a column of row numbers, joining the table to itself offset by a row, and then only picking rows where `VAL` has changed.

Each month has about half a billion records.  In total there's around 2.7 billion records.  The data is stored in DB2 BLU.  The table already has indices for `ITEM_NO`, `LOC`, and `ARCV_DATE`.  I only have `select` access to the table.

I think the big bottleneck is the `order by` in the select statement given that `n` is so large.  One idea I had was to try to do the sorting month-by-month and then union each of the months together.

Here's what I have so far:

```
with x as (
    select ITEM_NO, LOC, ARCV_DATE, VAL, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ITEM_NO, LOC, ARCV_DATE) as RN
    from MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE a
    where 
        ARCV_DATE >= '2017-06-01'
        and ARCV_DATE < '2017-07-01'
)
SELECT 
    x.ITEM_NO,
    x.LOC,
    y.ARCV_DATE as CHANGE_DATE, 
    y.VAL, 
    x.VAL as OLD_VAL
FROM x 
INNER JOIN x AS y
    ON x.rn = y.rn + 1
WHERE 
    x.VAL <> y.VAL
    and x.ITEM_NO = y.ITEM_NO
    and x.LOC = y.LOC
```

What could I do to improve performance on this for such a dataset?

Comment: Why LEFT JOIN y and also WHERE  y.VAL IS NOT NULL? You make it an INNER JOIN.

Comment: Um, good point.  Not sure how I missed that as I put it together.

Comment: You can add a new column 'Row_NUM' to the table. Do an one time insert of sequential row number based on the order (order by ITEM_NO, LOC, ARCV_DATE) you have specified in your query.  Going forward you can remove the row_numbering part from the query and join directly from the table. Will that work for you?

Comment: You mean add the ROW_NUM col to the original table?  Unfortunately, I only have select access to the table.

Comment: The first thing to do when you want to improve query performance is to look at its execution plan.

Comment: @Valli - unless you're building an analysis table, that's a _terrible_ thing to suggest: you're asking for a sequential numbering that involves **one** index.  In a "live", transactional table, there's no (good) way to do this - either the method chosen can result in gaps, or you have to completely serialize writes to the table.

Comment: Hm, part of your problem could just be that you're generating `ROW_NUMBER` off of the entire table, when all you're really interested in is sequential items for a given item/location pair.  What happens if you add `PARTITION BY` to the windowing clause (and removing item/location from the `ORDER BY`)?  This is likely to help you find a usable index, too, since then it could be fulfilled by an index on `(loc, item_no, arcv_date)`, instead of only `(item_no, loc, arcv_date)`

Comment: Side note, point of style: the conditions in the `WHERE` clause more properly belong as conditions in the given join's `ON` clause (note that the optimizer will effectively shift them there anyways - you'll get no speed benefit from this, but it groups conditions for the same thing, making reading the query easier).

Comment: @ Clockwork-Muse Yes I agree. If the value changes from one day to next day only, then we can add a condition "  AND currentval.ARCV_DATE = prevval.ARCV_DATE-1" . rather than using a rownumber. I just implemented this idea and added an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Without any write access your options are very limited because the query isn't that complex. You could try avoiding the join altogether by using LAG() OVER() such as this:

```
SELECT
      *
FROM (
      SELECT
            ITEM_NO
          , LOC
          , ARCV_DATE
          , VAL
          , LAG(ARCV_DATE, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM_NO, LOC ORDER BY ARCV_DATE DESC) AS CHANGE_DATE
          , LAG(VAL, 1)       OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM_NO, LOC ORDER BY ARCV_DATE DESC) AS OLD_VAL
      FROM MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE
      WHERE ARCV_DATE >= '2017-06-01'
      AND ARCV_DATE < '2017-07-01'
      ) d
WHERE ( VAL <> OLD_VAL OR OLD_VAL IS NULL )
```

But tuning this further could require adding or changing indexes.

Comment: Um, you need to add `PARTITION BY` (and deal with nulls), since the `WHERE` clause restricts to only comparing identical items/locations.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse good points so I have addressed them, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT currentval.ITEM,
        currentval.LOC
        currentval.ARCV_DATE currentdate
        prevval.ARCV_DATE Previousdate
        currentval.val currentval
        prevval.val Previousval           
  FROM MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE currentval JOIN
       MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE prevval ON
       currentval.ITEM_NO = prevval.ITEM_NO
 WHERE currentval.loc = prevval.loc
   AND currentval.val <> prevval.val
   AND currentval.ARCV_DATE = prevval.ARCV_DATE+1
   AND currentval.ARCV_DATE >= '2017-06-01'
   AND prevval.ARCV_DATE < '2017-07-01'
```

Assuming that values will change from one day to next day. This query will retrieve the values that changes from previous day to current day.

```
   AND currentval.ARCV_DATE = prevval.ARCV_DATE+1
```

Comment: ...please, don't use the implicit-join (comma-separated `FROM` clause) syntax.  You should always explicitly list joins and their conditions.